# Why does an existential type require a generic instead of an associated type?

Tags: generics, rust, existential-type, associated-types

I have an [existential type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.md#guide-existential-types) defined like this:

```
trait Collection {
    type Element;
}
impl<T> Collection for Vec<T> {
    type Element = T;
}

type Existential<T> = impl Collection<Element = T>;
```

A function, which takes a type implementing a trait with an associated type, returns this type.
Why does this code work:

```
fn return_existential<I, T>(iter: I) -> Existential<T>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    I::Item: Collection,
{
    let item = iter.into_iter().next().unwrap();
    vec![item]
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec849873aba09e9f7c4888083d2dba1b)

while this does not:

```
fn return_existential<I>(iter: I) -> Existential<I::Item>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Collection,
{
    let item = iter.into_iter().next().unwrap();
    vec![item]
}
```

```
error: type parameter `I` is part of concrete type but not used in parameter list for the `impl Trait` type alias
  --> src/lib.rs:16:1
   |
16 | / {
17 | |     let item = iter.into_iter().next().unwrap();
18 | |     vec![item]
19 | | }
   | |_^

error: defining opaque type use does not fully define opaque type
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | / fn return_existential<I>(iter: I) -> Existential<I::Item>
13 | | where
14 | |     I: IntoIterator,
15 | |     I::Item: Collection,
...  |
18 | |     vec![item]
19 | | }
   | |_^

error: could not find defining uses
  --> src/lib.rs:10:1
   |
10 | type Existential<T> = impl Collection<Element = T>;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fc59c81bbc6d54bac317911e074ba6e)

When using a `Vec` directly, this works fine:

```
fn return_existential<I>(iter: I) -> Vec<I::Item>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Collection,
{
    let item = iter.into_iter().next().unwrap();
    vec![item]
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=000b2ad6956592756ddc3e4b88467f9d)

*Note:* Those examples are constructed while playing around with this feature. I won't use it anyway as long as my IDE is not aware of existential types. Additionally, the exact syntax is subject to change.

Comment: Are you asking (1) why a Work In Progress feature does not seem to be fully implemented OR (2) whether there is a fundamental limitation linked to existential types?

Comment: @Matthieu The latter.

Comment: To me, this just looks like the feature isn't fully polished. You should report a bug.

Comment: I [filed this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511#issuecomment-486614871).

Comment: @oli-obk [replied to this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511#issuecomment-486698629): *I'm not 100% sure we can support this case out of the box* and proposed the same solution as in my first code snippet as workaround.